# MySQLi_STMT wrapper, allows placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've made a simple wrapper for `MySQLi_STMT`, allowing the usage of placeholders and spares you the need to manually bind variables. The full code is at the bottom of this question (it's quite large, with comments). Please give me feedback/criticisms on anything you want (readability and API design for starters).

Usage:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'testdb');
$statement = new Carrot\Database\MySQLi\StatementWrapper($mysqli,
   'SELECT
       id, name, balance
    FROM
       accounts
    WHERE
       name LIKE #name_like,
       balance > #balance_lower_limit'
);

$statement->execute(array('#name_like' => 'John%', '#balance_lower_limit' => 50000));

while ($row = $statement->fetchObject())
{
    echo $row->id, $row->name, $row->balance;
}
```

I've wrapped a lot of `MySQLi_STMT` methods/properties (like `set_attr` and `get_attr`) so the code might be too long (around 900 lines), is this a problem?

Code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/gikrWxFR - pastie: http://www.pastie.org/1965280 - or here: a couple of comment blocks deleted to fit:

```
namespace Carrot\Database\MySQLi;

class StatementWrapper
{
    /**
     * @var string Statement string with placeholders, injected during construction.
     */
    protected $statement_string_with_placeholders;

    /**
     * @var string Processed statement string, used in constructing the MySQLi_STMT object, placeholders replaced with '?'.
     */
    protected $statement_string;

    /**
     * @var MySQLi_STMT Instance of MySQLi_STMT, constructed using {@see $statement_string}.
     */
    protected $statement_object;

    /**
     * @var array List of placeholders with the hash (#) prefix, extracted from {@see $statement_string_with_placeholders}.
     */
    protected $placeholders;

    /**
     * @var array List of placeholders with 'blob' data type, set by the user - see {@see }.
     */
    protected $blob_params = array();

    /**
     * @var mixed Contains the result of MySQLi_STMT::result_metadata() call.
     */
    protected $result_metadata;

    /**
     * @var array Parameters used to execute the query.
     */
    protected $params;

    /**
     * @var string Parameter types in string, as per MySQLi_STMT::bind_param() specification.
     */
    protected $param_types;

    /**
     * @var array Result row, filled with new values every time a new row is fetched.
     */
    protected $result_row;

    /**
     * @var array Contains references to the {@see $params} property, used for binding in bind_param().
     */
    protected $references_params;

    /**
     * @var array Contains references to the {@see $result_row} property, used for binding in bind_result().
     */
    protected $references_result_row;

    /**
     * @var bool If set to true, any subsequent execution that fails/returns false will trigger an exception.
     */
    protected $throw_exception_when_execution_fails = false;

    /**
     * @var bool True if result set has been buffered using MySQLi_STMT::store_result(), false otherwise.
     */
    protected $result_is_buffered = false;

    public function __construct(\MySQLi $mysqli, $statement_string_with_placeholders)
    {
        $this->statement_string_with_placeholders = $statement_string_with_placeholders;
        $this->placeholders = $this->extractPlaceholders($statement_string_with_placeholders);
        $this->statement_string = $this->replacePlaceholdersWithQuestionMarks($statement_string_with_placeholders);
        $this->statement_object = $mysqli->prepare($this->statement_string);

        if (empty($this->statement_object) or !is_a($this->statement_object, '\MySQLi_STMT'))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper error, fails to prepare the statement. Error number: '{$mysqli->errno}', Error message: '{$mysqli->error}', Processed statement: '{$this->statement_string}', Original statement: '{$this->statement_string_with_placeholders}'.");
        }

        $this->result_metadata = $this->statement_object->result_metadata();
        $this->createParameterVariablesAndReferences();
        $this->createResultVariablesAndReferences();
        $this->bindResult();
    }

    /**
     * Executes the statement.
     *
     * Pass the parameters as associative array. Previously used
     * parameters will be used if you don't pass parameter array.
     * You don't need to pass anything if your statement doesn't
     * need parameters. 
     *
     * <code>
     * $statement = new StatementWrapper($mysqli, 'INSERT INTO accounts (id, first_name) VALUES (#id, #first_name));
     * $statement->execute(array('#id' => 'AB12345', '#first_name' => 'John'));
     * </code>
     * 
     * Will throw RuntimeException if execution fails and
     * $throw_exception_when_execution_fails is true.
     * 
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @see $throw_exception_when_execution_fails
     * @param array $params Optional. Parameters to use for execution, if left empty will use previously set parameters.
     * @return bool Returns true if statement executed successfully, false otherwise.
     *
     */
    public function execute(array $params = array())
    {
        if (!empty($params))
        {
            $this->setAndBindParameters($params);
        }

        $result = $this->statement_object->execute();

        if (!$result && $this->throw_exception_when_execution_fails)
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper execution error! Error #{$this->statement_object->errno}: '{$this->statement_object->error}', statement is '{$this->statement_string}'.");
        }

        // After each execution, you need to call MySQLi_STMT::store_result() again.
        $this->result_is_buffered = false;

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the result as enumerated array using MySQLi_STMT::fetch().
     * 
     * Calls to this method is ignored if the statement doesn't have 
     * result. Use while() loop to iterate the result set:
     *
     * <code>
     * while ($row = $statement->fetchArray())
     * {
     *     echo "ID: {$row[0]}, Name: {$row[1]}";
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * @return mixed Result row as enumerated array. False if no more rows or failure in fetching.
     *
     */
    public function fetchArray()
    {
        if (is_object($this->result_metadata) && is_a($this->result_metadata, '\MySQLi_Result'))
        {
            $result = $this->statement_object->fetch();

            if ($result === true)
            {
                $row = array();

                foreach ($this->result_row as $content)
                {
                    $row[] = $content;
                }

                return $row;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the result as associative array using MySQLi_STMT::fetch().
     * 
     * Calls to this method is ignored if the statement doesn't have 
     * result. Use while() loop to iterate the result set:
     *
     * <code>
     * while ($row = $statement->fetchAssociativeArray())
     * {
     *     echo "ID: {$row['id']}, Name: {$row['name']}";
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * @return mixed Result row as associative array. False if no more rows or failure in fetching.
     *
     */
    public function fetchAssociativeArray()
    {
        if (is_object($this->result_metadata) && is_a($this->result_metadata, '\MySQLi_Result'))
        {
            $result = $this->statement_object->fetch();

            if ($result === true)
            {
                $row = array();

                foreach ($this->result_row as $field_name => $content)
                {
                    $row[$field_name] = $content;
                }

                return $row;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the result as PHP standard object using MySQLi_STMT::fetch().
     * 
     * Calls to this method is ignored if the statement doesn't have 
     * result. Use while() loop to iterate the result set:
     *
     * <code>
     * while ($row = $statement->fetchObject())
     * {
     *     echo "ID: {$row->id}, Name: {$row->name}";
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * @return mixed Result row as PHP standard object. False if no more rows or failure in fetching.
     *
     */
    public function fetchObject()
    {
        if (is_object($this->result_metadata) && is_a($this->result_metadata, '\MySQLi_Result'))
        {
            $result = $this->statement_object->fetch();

            if ($result === true)
            {
                $row = array();

                foreach ($this->result_row as $field_name => $content)
                {
                    $row[$field_name] = $content;
                }

                return (object) $row;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Mark parameter placeholder as 'blob' type.
     *
     * For each statement execution, parameters are automatically
     * assigned proper type by detecting the parameter variable type
     * using is_integer(), is_float(), and is_string(). Parameter type
     * defaults to string. If you have to send a blob parameter type,
     * use this method to mark the placeholder as such.
     *
     * <code>
     * $statement->markParamAsBlob('#blob_param');
     * </code>
     *
     * @see $blob_params
     * @param string $placeholder The placeholder you want to mark as blob, with hash (#).
     *
     */
    public function markParamAsBlob($placeholder)
    {
        if (!isset($this->placeholders[$placeholder]))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper error in marking parameter as blob. Placeholder '{$placeholder}' is not defined.");
        }

        $this->blob_params[] = $placeholder;
    }

    /**
     * Tells the class to throw/not to throw exceptions when statement execution fails.
     *
     * Default behavior is to NOT throw exception when the query fails
     * and simply return false. This makes it easier for single statements,
     * however if you need to craft a transaction, you can tell this
     * class to throw exception if execution fails (for whatever reason).
     *
     * <code>
     * $statement->throwExceptionWhenExecutionFails(true);
     * </code>
     *
     * @param bool $bool Pass true to throw exceptions, false otherwise.
     *
     */
    public function throwExceptionWhenExecutionFails($bool)
    {
        $this->throw_exception_when_execution_fails = $bool;
    }

    /**
     * See if the result set is buffered or not.
     *
     * The result set is buffered if MySQLi_STMT::store_result() is
     * called after each statement execution. The wrapper notes this
     * by setting $result_is_buffered property to true every time
     * MySQLi_STMT::store_result() is called.
     *
     * The wrapper does not buffer the result by default, following
     * MySQLi_STMT standard behavior.
     *
     * If the result set is not buffered, MySQLi_STMT->num_rows() will
     * not return a valid response.
     *
     * @return bool True if buffered, false otherwise.
     *
     */
    public function resultIsBuffered()
    {
        return $this->result_is_buffered;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the result metadata.
     *
     * This method does not wrap/call MySQLi_STMT::result_metadata(),
     * it simply returns a saved value since MySQLi_STMT::result_metadata()
     * is already called in construction.
     *
     * @return mixed Instance of MySQLi_Result or false if there isn't a result.
     *
     */
    public function getResultMetadata()
    {
        return $this->result_metadata;
    }

    /**
     * Destroys this object.
     *
     * Calls MySQLi_STMT::close() for safety.
     *
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->result_is_buffered = false;
        $this->statement_object->close();
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->affected_rows.
     * 
     * @return mixed -1 indicates query error.
     *
     */
    public function getAffectedRows()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->affected_rows;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::attr_get().
     * 
     * @param int $attr The attribute you want to get.
     * @return mixed False if the attribute is not found, otherwise return value of the attribute.
     *
     */
    public function getAttr($attr)
    {
        return $this->statement_object->attr_get($attr);
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::attr_set().
     *
     * @param int $attr The attribute you want to set.
     * @param int $mode The value to assign to the attribute.
     *
     */
    public function setAttr($attr, $mode)
    {
        $this->statement_object->attr_set($attr, $mode);
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::data_seek().
     *
     * @param int $offset
     *
     */
    public function dataSeek($offset)
    {
        $this->statement_object->data_seek($offset);
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->errno.
     *
     * @return int Error number for the last execution.
     *
     */
    public function getErrorNo()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->errno;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->error.
     * 
     * @return string Error message for last execution.
     *
     */
    public function getErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->error;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->field_count.
     *
     * @return int Number of fields in the given statement.
     *
     */
    public function getFieldCount()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->field_count;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::free_result().
     *
     * This method also notes that result buffer has been cleared by
     * setting $result_is_buffered property to false.
     *
     * When you run a prepared statement that returns a result set, it
     * locks the connection unless you free_result() or store_result().
     *
     */
    public function freeResult()
    {
        $this->statement_object->free_result();
        $this->result_is_buffered = false;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::get_warnings().
     *
     * @return mixed
     *
     */
    public function getWarnings()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->get_warnings();
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->insert_id.
     *
     * @return int The ID generated from previous INSERT operation.
     *
     */
    public function getInsertID()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->insert_id;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->num_rows.
     *
     * This method does not return invalid row count, it returns false
     * if result set is not buffered.
     * 
     * @return mixed Number of rows if result is buffered, false if result set is not buffered.
     *
     */
    public function getNumRows()
    {
        if ($this->result_is_buffered)
        {
            return $this->statement_object->num_rows;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->param_count.
     *
     * @return int $param_count Number of parameters in the statement.
     *
     */
    public function getParamCount()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->param_count;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::reset().
     *
     * MySQLi_STMT::reset does not unbind parameter. After you reset, you
     * can safely execute it again even if the query has parameters.
     *
     * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
     *
     */
    public function reset()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->reset();
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT->sqlstate.
     *
     * @return string SQLSTATE error from previous statement operation.
     *
     */
    public function getSQLState()
    {
        return $this->statement_object->sqlstate;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for MySQLi_STMT::store_result().
     *
     * This method also sets $result_is_buffered property to true,
     * allowing you getNumRows() method to return valid value. This
     * method must be called *after* execution.
     *
     * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
     *
     */
    public function storeResult()
    {
        $this->result_is_buffered = $this->statement_object->store_result();
        return $this->result_is_buffered;
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Extracts placeholder names from original statement string.
     *
     * Placeholder is defined with this regular expression:
     *
     * <code>
     * #[a-zA-Z0-9_#]+
     * </code>
     *
     * Since the hash character (#) is used in MySQL to mark comments,
     * chances are you won't be using it in your query other than for
     * marking placeholders. List of example placeholder that will
     * match:
     *
     * <code>
     * #placeholder
     * #123placeholder
     * #_place_holder
     * ##placeholder
     * #place#holder
     * </code>
     *
     * @param string $statement_string_with_placeholders
     * @return array Array that contains placeholder names.
     *
     */
    protected function extractPlaceholders($statement_string_with_placeholders)
    {
        preg_match_all('/#[a-zA-Z0-9_#]+/', $statement_string_with_placeholders, $matches);

        if (isset($matches[0]) && is_array($matches[0]))
        {
            return $matches[0];
        }

        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Replaces placeholders (#string) with '?'.
     *
     * This in effect creates a statement string that we can use it
     * to instantiate a MySQLi statement object. It replaces this
     * pattern:
     *
     * <code>
     * #[a-zA-Z0-9_#]+
     * </code>
     *
     * with question mark ('?'). Returns empty array if no placeholder
     * is found.
     *
     * @param string $statement_string_with_placeholders
     * @return string Statement string safe to use as MySQLi_STMT instantiation argument.
     *
     */
    protected function replacePlaceholdersWithQuestionMarks($statement_string_with_placeholders)
    {
        return preg_replace('/#[a-zA-Z0-9_#]+/', '?', $statement_string_with_placeholders);
    }

    /**
     * Creates parameter array to store parameters and a set of references that refers to it.
     * 
     * We create parameter array to store parameters set by the user,
     * and we create an array that references those parameters to be
     * used as arguments when we use call_user_func() to call
     * MySQLi_STMT::bind_param().
     * 
     * @see $params
     * @see $references_params
     * @see __construct()
     * 
     */
    protected function createParameterVariablesAndReferences()
    {
        $placeholder_count = count($this->placeholders);

        if ($this->statement_object->param_count != $placeholder_count)
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper error, fails to prepare the statement. Parameter count ({$this->statement_object->param_count}) and placeholder count ({$placeholder_count}) does not match.");
        }

        $this->references_params['types'] = &$this->param_types;

        foreach ($this->placeholders as $placeholder)
        {
            $this->params[$placeholder] = null;
            $this->references_params[$placeholder] = &$this->params[$placeholder];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates array to store a fetched result row and a set of references that refers to it.
     *
     * We create result row variables as an array to store each value
     * every time we fetch using MySQLi_STMT::fetch(). We create
     * references to these result row variables to be passed when we
     * use call_user_func() to call MySQLi_STMT::bind_result().
     *
     * @see $result_row
     * @see $references_result_row
     * @see __construct()
     *
     */
    protected function createResultVariablesAndReferences()
    {
        if (is_object($this->result_metadata) && is_a($this->result_metadata, '\MySQLi_Result'))
        {
            foreach ($this->result_metadata->fetch_fields() as $field)
            {
                $this->result_row[$field->name] = null;
                $this->references_result_row[$field->name] = &$this->result_row[$field->name];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Binds result row references using MySQLi_STMT::bind_result().
     * 
     * We only need to bind the result once, hence this method is called
     * only at the constructor.
     *
     * @see $result_row
     * @see $references_result_row
     * @see __construct()
     *
     */
    protected function bindResult()
    {
        if (is_object($this->result_metadata) && is_a($this->result_metadata, '\MySQLi_Result'))
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this->statement_object, 'bind_result'), $this->references_result_row);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets and binds parameters for the next execution.
     *
     * Will throw RuntimeException if the parameter array count doesn't
     * match the parameter/placeholder count.
     *
     * Will throw RuntimeException if the parameter index doesn't contain
     * all placeholders as its indexes.
     * 
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @see execute()
     * @param array $params Complete parameter array, indexed with placeholders.
     *
     */
    protected function setAndBindParameters(array $params)
    {
        // Ignore method call if we don't have parameters to process
        if ($this->statement_object->param_count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $user_param_count = count($params);
        $param_type_string = '';

        if ($this->statement_object->param_count != $user_param_count)
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper error when setting and binding parameters. Argument count ({$user_param_count}) doesn't match needed parameter count ({$this->statement_object->param_count}).");
        }

        foreach ($this->params as $placeholder => $param)
        {
            if (!isset($params[$placeholder]))
            {
                throw new \RuntimeException("StatementWrapper error when setting and binding parameters. Required parameter '{$placeholder}' is not defined when trying to set parameter.");
            }

            $this->params[$placeholder] = $params[$placeholder];
        }

        $this->createParamTypeString();
        $this->bindParam();
    }

    /**
     * Fills parameter types string to the $references_param property.
     * 
     * MySQLi_STMT::bind_param() requires us to specify parameter types
     * when binding. Allowed parameter types are (as per 5.3.6):
     *
     * <code>
     * i - integer
     * d - double
     * s - string
     * b - blob (will be sent in packets)
     * </code>
     *
     * This method detects if the parameter is integer or float (double)
     * and defaults to string. To mark a parameter as blob, use class
     * method markParamAsBlob().
     *
     * @see $references_params
     * @see setAndBindParameters()
     * @see markParamAsBlob()
     *
     */
    protected function createParamTypeString()
    {
        $this->references_params['types'] = '';

        foreach ($this->params as $placeholder => $param)
        {
            if (in_array($placeholder, $this->blob_params))
            {
                $this->references_params['types'] .= 'b';
            }
            else if (is_integer($param))
            {
                $this->references_params['types'] .= 'i';
            }
            else if (is_float($param))
            {
                $this->references_params['types'] .= 'd';
            }
            else
            {
                $this->references_params['types'] .= 's';
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Binds parameter references array using MySQLi_STMT::bind_param().
     *
     * This method is called each time the user provides new arguments.
     * Assumes that parameter types string has already been generated.
     *
     * @see $references_params
     * @see createParameterVariablesAndReferences()
     *
     */
    protected function bindParam()
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($this->statement_object, 'bind_param'), $this->references_params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before reading the actually implementation:**

What you doing is a `pdo`-like placeholder syntax with a `#` instead of a `:` and without the need to bind the parameters directly but only pass in a array.

I can see the 'need' for something like this as binding parameters with pdo isn't quite what frameworks seems to want their users to do. `ZF, ezC/zetaC, SF` and so on to name samples.

The `$statement` it's self is then able to `execute` and then `$row = $statement->fetch`.

This strikes me as a little bit odd as most things that allow for `execution` also expect `prepare`ation when it comes to queries but thats just method naming.

The statement is just one class acting as a query execution AND a result provider. That maybe could be splitted into two.

### The implementation:

**`__construct`**

You are doing **quite** a lot of work in the constructor. From a testing point that might be a problem, at least [**`misko disagrees with doing work in the constructor`**](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Check for that, not for `empty` and `is_a`. Also see: `instanceof` instead of is_a for that case.

---

**`execute`**

`if(!empty($params))` for a `array` is equal to `if($params)`

and i don't like the "how to do error handling switch" if thats the base class of a framework. It should just work one way.. i guess. I can see the point of giving the user choice but then you should at least use return codes if you don't throw exceptions.

**`fetch*`**

The fetch functions feels like duplicate code

**`mysqli_stmt::attr_*`**

What's your usecase for those functions? Are those really needed?

---

Apart from that the code seems kinda fine.. given how bad the `mysqli_stmt->bind*` functions are with their reliance on references.

I haven't looked to deep into the `#foo param` replace logic but I'm not sure if `$this->statement_object->param_count != $placeholder_count` is the proper way to do error handling there. Can't i use the same placeholder twice? To i have to use all of them? If so why does it not make sure... and so on.

Hoped that helped a little

Comment: thanks for the detailed review! Agreed on most part, Re the constructor: I agree that it looks bad, however - it doesn't do anything but initializing the class properties and instantiating the `MySQLi_STMT` class - agree on the `mysqli_prepare` and `fetch` duplicate code

Comment: I wasn't sure on making a wrapper of `mysqli_stmt::attr_*` too, but I added it anyway since somebody might wanted to use it. I agree it's most likely YAGNI.

Comment: @rick Well it does call `$this->statement_object = $mysqli->prepare($this->statement_string);` so it does quite a lot as it talks to the database at that point. Also sanitizing **could** be qualified as work too. I'm not too sure on that myself